# Scala model-view-presenter, traits

Tags: scala, macros, mvp

I am a fan of Martin Fowler's (deprecated) model-view-presenter pattern. I am writing a Scala view class containing several button classes. I would like to include methods to set the action properties of the buttons, to be called by the presenter. A typical code fragment looks like this:

```
private val aButton = new JButton
def setAButtonAction(action: Action): Unit = { aButton.setAction(action) }
```

This code is repeated for each button. If Java/Scala had the C preprocessor, I would create a macro to generate this code, given the button name (no lectures on the evils of the C preprocessor, please). This code is obviously very verbose and repetitive. Is there any better way way to do this in Scala, perhaps using traits?

Please hold the lectures about scala.swing. I looking for a general pattern here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala is less about explicit setter and getter methods than java. Instead use abstract fields to define the exposed interface. How about something like this:

```
trait ActionUser {
  def setAction(action:Action):Unit
}

trait Container {
  val aButton:ActionUser
}

trait ContainerImpl {
  val aButton = new JButton with ActionUser
}
```

Classes operating against `Container` will only be able to access `setAction` while internal methods see it as a JButton.

One more note: C uses macros to cut down on code duplication. Scala uses multi-inheritance of traits to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: nice answer. I'm going to explore this further.

Comment: @Ralph did you explore it? Can you share your skeleton code for MVP in Scala? I asked this question with bounty worth, please check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631080/mvp-in-scala-swing

Comment: @MyTitle: I started a project several years that explored this, but had to move on to another project and never went back. If I had to do it, though, I would use the pattern shown in sblundy's answer.